# Find specific string, then copy the word after it and concatenate it to a variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

Lets say I run a **command~#./testapp.sh** or for instance linux **command~#dmesg** and any of this sample command prints the following line in the linux terminal :

> -random long line ---long line----
>   size of    : 12
>   mydata    : 0x5b
>   mydata    : 0xa8
>   mydata    : 0xcc
>   mydata    : 0x18
>   mydata    : 0x15
>   mydata    : 0x18
>   --random line--

I would like to then search for the all keyword after'0x', concatenate and store this variables (eg: 5b, a8, cc) as a string in a string variable called test_variable.The content of test_variable should look like "5ba8cc181518" . I would like to do this in python 2.7.

Here is my attempted code:

```
import sys
import os
import re
import time
import string

test_variable = ""
test_variable = re.findall(r' bx(\W)',os.system("dmesg")) 
test_variable += test_variable
print "content is : " + test_variables
```

Comment: Simply invoking os.system will **not** capture the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a non-regex solution like so:

```
sample = os.popen('dmesg').read()

# Sample
sample = """
-random long line ---long line----
size of : 12
mydata : 0x5b
mydata : 0xa8
mydata : 0xcc
mydata : 0x18
mydata : 0x15
mydata : 0x18 --random line--
"""

concat_out = ''.join([word.replace("0x","") 
                      for word in sample.split()
                      if word.startswith("0x")])
print(concat_out)
```

To get "5ba8cc181518"

Answer (score 0):

re.findall() will return a list, not a string. To convert it to string, use:

```
''.join(re.findall(...))
```

Now for the regex, I'd suggest the following:

```
matches = re.findall(r'mydata\s*\:\s*0x([0-9a-f]{2})', sample_data, re.IGNORECASE)
test_variable = ''.join(matches)
```

It's a little more restrictive on what it will accept as valid code.

If you're absolutely sure "0x" is guaranteed to identify the code and will never appear anywhere else, you can simplify this as:

```
matches = re.findall(r'0x([0-9a-f]{2})', sample_data, re.IGNORECASE)
```

Essentially, this regex looks for "0x" followed by 2 hexadecimal digits.

Answer (score 0):

`os.system('dmesg')` returns only the *[returncode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?highlight=os.system#os.system)* after executing `dmesg`,

You would rather use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module instead this way:

```
import re
import subprocess

test_variable = subprocess.check_output('dmesg',shell=True)
result = ''.join(re.findall(r'0x([0-9a-f]{2}', test_variable))
```